# How to record frames of Leap Motion for Hand Tremor Tracking in C#?

Tags: c#, youtube, signal-processing, frame, leap-motion

I've already seen in Youtube about [Leap Motion Tremor Recognition](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7o1v7RayEV8) and start to build this app with using Leap Motion for signal processing in C#. I get some problems in first step. I don't know how to get and record some frames of hand motion per second. In this case, I want to record it in 10 seconds. I don't know the library what I must use for record this.

hope somebody help me to explain and share how to code it in C#... thanks

this is the code I have tried but I don't build and run it, so I think it doesn't work. Could anyone check it for me?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Leap;

namespace map3
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window, ILeapEventDelegate
{

    private Controller controller = new Controller();
    Leap.Frame frame;

    //getting data from a frame
    HandList hands;
    PointableList pointables;
    FingerList fingers;
    ToolList tools;


    private LeapEventListener listener;
    private Gesture gesture = new Gesture();
    private String direction;
    Leap.Frame gestureFrame;
    Leap.Frame fingerFrame;

    private long timestamp;

    private Boolean isClosing = false;
    private Boolean isPlaying = false;

    private Int64 lastFrameID = 0;

    Thread finger_thread, gesture_thread;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        main_window.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;

        this.controller = new Controller();
        this.listener = new LeapEventListener(this);
        controller.AddListener(listener);
        processFrame(frame);

        //get timestamp
        float framePeriod = controller.Frame(0).Timestamp - controller.Frame(1).Timestamp;
        lbl_debug.Content = "Gesture";
    }

    private void processFrame(Leap.Frame frame)
    {
        if (frame.Id == lastFrameID)
            return;
        lastFrameID = frame.Id;

       //for have an ID of an entity from a different frame
        Hand hand = frame.Hand(handID);
        Pointable pointable = frame.Pointable(pointableID);
        Finger finger = frame.Finger(fingerID);
        Tool tool = frame.Tool(toolID);

        Thread.Sleep(10000);

        //to save frame to file
        byte[] serializedFrame = frame.Serialize;
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes ("frame.data", serializedFrame);
    }

    public void Deserialize() //to read multiple frame  from the saved file
    {
        Controller leapController = new Controller();
        using (System.IO.BinaryReader br =
            new System.IO.BinaryReader(System.IO.File.Open("file.data", System.IO.FileMode.Open)))
        {
            while (br.BaseStream.Position < br.BaseStream.Length)
            {
                Int32 nextBlock = br.ReadInt32();
                byte[] frameData = br.ReadBytes(nextBlock);
                Leap.Frame newFrame = new Leap.Frame();
                newFrame.Deserialize(frameData);
            }
        }

    }

    private void btn_start_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        startDetect();
    }


    private void startDetect()
    {
        //maplayer.Play();
        if (controller.IsConnected)
        {
            Leap.Frame frame = controller.Frame(); //the latest frame
            Leap.Frame previous = controller.Frame(1); //the previous frame
        }
        isPlaying = true;
        btn_start.Content = FindResource("Start"); //connecting to gui
    }

    delegate void LeapEventDelegate(string EventName);
    public void LeapEventNotification(string EventName)
    {
        if (this.CheckAccess())
        {
            switch (EventName)
            {
                case "onInit":
                    Debug.WriteLine("Init");
                    break;
                case "onConnect":
                    this.connectHandler();
                    break;
                case "onFrame":
                    if (!this.isClosing)
                        this.processFrame(this.controller.Frame());
                    break;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new LeapEventDelegate(LeapEventNotification), new object[] { EventName });
        }
    }

    void connectHandler()
    {
        this.controller.SetPolicy(Controller.PolicyFlag.POLICY_IMAGES);
        this.controller.EnableGesture(Gesture.GestureType.TYPE_SWIPE);
        this.controller.Config.SetFloat("Gesture.Swipe.MinLength", 200.0f);
        this.controller.Config.Save();
    }


    void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.isClosing = true;
        this.controller.RemoveListener(this.listener);
        this.controller.Dispose();
    }

    private void ListView_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public int handID { get; set; }

    public int pointableID { get; set; }

    public int toolID { get; set; }

    public int fingerID { get; set; }
}

public interface ILeapEventDelegate
{
    void LeapEventNotification(string EventName);
}

public class FrameListener : Listener
{
    public void onFrame(Controller controller)
    {
        Leap.Frame frame = controller.Frame();
        Leap.Frame previous = controller.Frame(1);
    }
}

public class LeapEventListener : Listener
{
    ILeapEventDelegate eventDelegate;

    public LeapEventListener(ILeapEventDelegate delegateObject)
    {
        this.eventDelegate = delegateObject;
    }
    public override void OnInit(Controller controller)
    {
        this.eventDelegate.LeapEventNotification("onInit");
    }
    public override void OnConnect(Controller controller)
    {
        controller.SetPolicy(Controller.PolicyFlag.POLICY_IMAGES);
        controller.EnableGesture(Gesture.GestureType.TYPE_SWIPE);
        this.eventDelegate.LeapEventNotification("onConnect");
    }

    public override void OnFrame(Controller controller)
    {
        this.eventDelegate.LeapEventNotification("onFrame");
    }
    public override void OnExit(Controller controller)
    {
        this.eventDelegate.LeapEventNotification("onExit");
    }
    public override void OnDisconnect(Controller controller)
    {
        this.eventDelegate.LeapEventNotification("onDisconnect");
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: I've edited this post

Comment: Inside the LeapMotion SDK there is a sample to record your hand motion and play back.
I think that is what you are looking for. I found them in C# on the unity3d assets.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I got to following solution in the Frame.cs.

To serialize the frame:

```
public byte[] Serialize
{
    get
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bf.Serialize(ms, this);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

To deserialize the frame:

```
public void Deserialize(byte[] arg)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        ms.Write(arg, 0, arg.Length);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        Frame objArray = (Frame)bf.Deserialize(ms);
        this.Id = objArray.Id;
        this.Timestamp = objArray.Timestamp;
        this.CurrentFramesPerSecond = objArray.CurrentFramesPerSecond;
        this.InteractionBox = objArray.InteractionBox;
        this.Hands = objArray.Hands;
    }

}
```

Therefore the InteractionBox has to be serializable in InteractionBox.cs:

```
[System.Serializable]
public struct InteractionBox{...}
```

The problem persits if you use the *.cs files from the source folder in the project. If you want to deserialize the frame in a different application you should build a DLL from your source folder with the updated sourcecode.  E.g. record frames in one program and play it back in another.

```
csc /t:library /out:Leap.dll LeapC.cs Arm.cs Bone.cs CircularObjectBuffer.cs ClockCorrelator.cs Config.cs Connection.cs Controller.cs CopyFromLeapCExtensions.cs CopyFromOtherExtensions.cs CSharpExtensions.cs Device.cs DeviceList.cs DistortionData.cs DistortionDictionary.cs Events.cs FailedDevice.cs FailedDeviceList.cs Finger.cs Frame.cs Hand.cs IController.cs Image.cs ImageData.cs ImageFuture.cs InteractionBox.cs LeapQuaternion.cs LeapTransform.cs Logger.cs Matrix.cs MessageSeverity.cs ObjectPool.cs PendingImages.cs PooledObject.cs StructMarshal.cs TimeBracket.cs TransformExtensions.cs Vector.cs
```

The original LeapC.dll still needs to be included as per SDK documentation.

Hope that helps.